# How to convert Date and Time column to just time as a decimal

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, time, decimal

Does anybody know how I can convert a date and time column to a decimal column based on the time only?

**For example:**

```
Select  StaffNum, Name, ContractHours    
From StaffContract    
Where StaffNum = 00123
```

Returns

```
**StaffNum**--------**Name**----------------**ContractHours** 

00123-----------Shaw, Jason--------2012-10-01 07:30:000
```

Instead of the `ContractHours` column showing  `'2012-10-01 **07:30:000**'` I need it to show the time section only and convert it to a decimal so instead of 07:30 **I need it to show 7.5**

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using sql 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`datepart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to extract parts of the date:

```
SELECT  StaffNum, 
        Name,
        DATEPART(hour, ContractHours) + (DATEPART(minute, ContractHours) / 60.0)
FROM    StaffContract    
WHERE   StaffNum = 00123
```